# How to change email template for new user?

Tags: wordpress, email, templates

When I add a new customer the email goes to new user in this format:

```
From: WordPress [wordpress@siteurl.com]
Subject: [site name] Your user name and password
Message:
         username: user
         Password: password
         siteurl.com/wp-login.php
```

Now I want to change this format like this:

```
From: My Site Name [info@siteurl.com]
Subject: siteurl.com customer account activated
Message:
       Your customer account has been activated.

       Your Login credentials are:

       Username: user email
       Password: password

       Thanks,
       abcd
```

I tried [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15304/how-to-change-the-default-registration-email-plugin-and-or-non-plugin), but it's not working.

Comment: You have another seven questions in which you've requested special attention over other questions - we prefer that requests for urgency are not added to questions here. Bear in mind that this is just noise once the question has aged, but moreover people who answer at sites like _Stack Overflow_ are volunteers, and they will answer questions at their leisure. I am adding an apologetic downvote to remind.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the notification function as recommend by the Codex

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_new_user_notification